# Why isn't my Python logging setup working?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

My code looks like this

```py
import logging

formatter = logging.Formatter("{asctime} - {name} - {levelname} - {message}",
                              "%d-%b-%y %H:%M", "{")


def _add_handler(handler: logging.StreamHandler) -> logging.StreamHandler:
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.setLevel(20)
    return handler

logging.basicConfig(
    handlers={
        _add_handler(logging.FileHandler("filename.log")),
        _add_handler(logging.StreamHandler())
    })
logging.info("hello world")
```

What this is *supposed* to do is log `"hello world"` both to the console and a file named `filename.log`, with a severity of `INFO`, which is what the `20` in the `setLevel` method is for. However, nothing is being logged at all. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the logging level for the logger as well. By default, it's set to `logging.WARNING`, so neither handler is seeing the message, let alone determining if it should be handled.

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    handlers={
        _add_handler(logging.FileHandler("filename.log")),
        _add_handler(logging.StreamHandler())
    })
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I was about to answer the exact same thing. Please note the use of logging.INFO instead of the literal 20 - this should be changed in the handler as well.

Comment: Eh, I would prefer using the constants, but using an `int` literal isn't wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to Stack Overflow and I've heard a lot of bad stuff about it, so I was lowkey scared about posting here

Comment: Glad to see you here despite what you heard, hope you had a good first experience! :)